# How to effectively drive 12 displays to preserve resolution & aspect ratio

Tags: video, multiple-monitors

Let me start by saying I am a web/software developer by trade, and not too familiar with the world of AV, Aspect Ratios, and the rest.  I know I like my 1080p monitor, and keep it at that.

I have the potential for a freelance job that will involve building a piece of software that will run on a PC and drive a Video Wall based on 12 displays.  We are not 100% sure of the displays yet as the client is still deciding what they want, but for arguments sake we can assume it will be comparable to [Samsung's Video Wall](http://www.samsung.com/uk/business/business-products/large-format-display/video-wall) offerings.  I am tasked with building the software, and the machine which the software will run on, and connect to those displays.

At a high-level, the software is going to be reading the DOW Jones, and depending on the value, play a piece of stock footage on the Video Wall that correlates to the market's performance.

The software is the least concerning part of the project for me.  I am more concerned with the computer I need to build, and how well it will drive the media selections on the screens.

My most pressing questions are:

- How many video cards do I need?  Do I want to stick with Nvidia?  I am a gamer by habit, so I assume I want a Nvidia 770, but is there another brand or line of video card more in line with what I need?
- Is there an 'out-of-the-box' rack-mounted or tower PC I could purchase that will do what I need?
- All of the stock footage I am finding will be in 1080p format.  Will I be able to 'downscale' the video wall to collectively equal 1080p so as to not pixelate my videos?
- How would I downscale the video wall?  I assume with my video card drivers? If I can downscale the video wall, would 1080p look like crap on that large of a display.

*If this question is improperly worded, or does not belong here, I apologize.  Please don't downvote me, just tell me and I will delete the question.*

Comment: If you are just displaying basic stuff, get two AMD card with 6 displayports connectors each. That will cut it down to two cards. As to pre-build, this sounds like something for which you want to use server class hardware (dual PSU's, remote access via iLO/DRAC/...). I would love to build something liek this for fun, but I suspect that talking to a HP or Dell representative to fullfil your HW needs is the better solution.

Comment: @Hennes I don't think it will work like that. [AMD FAQ](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/faqs.aspx#crossfire-technology) states that all monitors in Crossfire Eyefinity setup have to be connected to the primary graphics card, so you're still limited to 6 screens.

Comment: I did not mean in crossfire. Neither AMD Crossfire or Nvidia SLI will work since they will only use the outputs on one card. However you can use multiple card without crossfire or SLI. I pointed to the 6 DP port cards since they are relative cheap and two of those is a lot more manageable than 3 or 4 other cards with 3 working outputs each.

Comment: @Hennes Do you have an example card, or card model I could look at online that will show me more of what you are talking about?

Comment: [This](http://www.amazon.com/PowerColor-Eyefinity-Edition-DisplayPort-PCI-Express/dp/B009B5WTKO) is the first example I found. Disclaimer: I do not work for Powercolour or Amazon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this.  Resolution is going to be the key factor.  The higher the resolution per display, the more video cards you will need to push the pixels.  You can either output one high resolution signal and have screen splitter hardware split it to the different displays or you can output to each monitor as an individual screen and use a multi-monitor setup.

Windows itself will support well more than the 12 displays you are looking at using.  DisplayPort can support up to 4 monitors through a single port, so you would need at least 3 DisplayPort connectors (and likely 3 video cards) to do it as a multi-monitor setup (which would also give the highest resolution).  You could then simply arrange them in Windows as a giant desktop area to be used for display.

Alternately, if resolution isn't going to be super high, it may be simpler to treat it as one or two outputs going to video wall splitters such as [these](http://www.indstech.com/index.php?lang=en&sn=3637&c=2381).  That particular manufacturer only makes two by two and three by three adapters, but the idea is that they take in a single feed and then split it out to the panels via a direct mapping.  It's a little bit easier as far as plugging any source in to it, but might cost a bit more overall and does have more limited resolution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Resolution definitely is going to be key.  Thus why I was concerned with having the ability to have my 12 screen video wall equal one 1080p display.  

I am still a bit confused by the Video Wall Splitter.  So if I have 12 displays, I split them into groups of 3 per the support of the splitters.  I would then need 4 splitters to group the 12 displays into groups of 3's.  Then run the 4 splitters to my PC graphics cards.  Then modify my screen settings inside of windows?

Comment: @stat30fbliss - you could look to see if you can find one that handles your arrangement.  That was just the first example I found of the splitters.  Note that the place I linked is 2x2 (4 screens) and 3x3 (9-screens).  I'm not sure how you were planning on organizing 12 screens as that's likely not going to be the correct aspect ratio for 1080p.  You can either use the graphics cards to output to all displays or let a stand alone unit handle splitting and dividing a 1080p source) which would allow for hooking it in to any computer or display source).